# How to change Bluetooth channel used by Google Earth

Tags: macos, bluetooth, gps

This might be more a Google Earth issue, but here goes.

I've paired my Mountain Lion laptop with a Garmin Bluetooth GPS, and can confirm getting NMEA data over the serial channel with

`cat /dev/tty.GarminGPS10-Gps10`

However, when I try to connect to the GPS inside Google Earth, I see the message

> Reading /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync

and nothing happens. How do I point Google Earth to the proper tty?

I've tried:

- removing my Android phone from know Bluetooth devices
- reinstalling Google Earth and reinstalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Seems Google Earth cycles through all available COM ports until it finds a feed. Left it on for a while and it connected to the correct port eventually